# Session data to text file showing nothing

Tags: php

I have created something that once text is put inside of a text box and submit is pressed it sends this to a server and it is then stored in a session. On the press of another button you can retrieve this text and it is then transferred from the session to a txt file.

Yesterday I had this working and it was printing to my txt file but now all of a sudden it wont do it at all, can anyone spot any issues that would cause this?

This is ran when the retrieve button is pressed:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
    print_r($_SESSION ["input_data"]);

    $myfile = fopen("TestingOut.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = $_SESSION["input_data"];
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
 ?>
```

I have narrowed it down to the     $_SESSION["input_data"]    part as it will print some random text in place for he session as seen above.

This is the creation of the session array:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php
   $_SESSION["input_data"][] = $_POST["input"];
   echo $_POST["input"];
?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION["input_data"][] = $_POST["input"]` creates an array but `fwrite` requires a string.

Comment: I am using $txt to write my array out as a string into  the generated text file, I don't see why this shouldn't work or print nothing. *edit* I see, 
I must use implode() or something.

Comment: You assign an array to `$_SESSION["input_data"]`, then that to `$txt`, then pass it to `fwrite`. Have you checked for any PHP errors?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @marekful , I was tryign to print an array into a text file, I used implode() to fix this:

```
$strings = implode(" ", $_SESSION["input_data"]);
$myfile = fopen("TestingOut.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $strings;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```